# Ubunto 19.10 stuck with soft lockup cpu stuck after kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, watchdog

I am about a month new to linux and am running Ubuntu on an Asus VivoBook laptop (F512D) in a dual boot with Windows. Ubuntu installed smoothly and I have been using it for about a month with no problem. 2 days ago I opted to install the latest system updates. After restarting to finalize the update I am stuck in this screen:

19.10 watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [systemd-udevd:416]

I have been searching for a solution to this and have tried various edits of grub but nothing seems to be working.

One recurring theme others seem to have is video drivers. But I don't know how to go about determining if that is the issue in my case or not, or how to solve it.

I can boot to recovery mode but not sure what to do now to fix the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I would love to be up and running again.

**EDIT**

I discovered I can boot to previous kernel 5.3.0-29 in normal mode. The one I am having trouble with is 5.3.0-40.

I am gladdened that I can access ubuntu and my system again! But I am unsure what to do from here. Should I delete the kernel that doesn't work? If so, what about next time there is a kernel update? Or do I need to fix a driver issue?

Comment: Likely driver issue as you say. Kernel updates can do that. In recovery mode terminal go  'journalctl -xe`. Do you see errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @stephenboston Here is the only error I see in the output. I don't know if it is relevant. *Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"*